# Additive log ratio transformation on a dataset using alr() | addLR()

Tags: r, statistics, transformation

I am attempting to perform an additive log ratio transformation on a dataset. When I run the addLR() function, I receive the error code:

> Error in if (dim(x)[2] < 2) stop("data must be of dimension greater equal 2") : argument is of length zero

When I run `str(df)` the structure of my data frame returns as:

```
'data.frame':   1020 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SUB: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ NEW  : num  2.5 351.4 0.9 49.8 80 ...
```

Here's my code:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
df$newVar <- addLR(df$NEW, ivar=ncol(df$SUB))
```

I've also used the function

```
df$newVar <- alr(df$NEW, ivar=ncol(df$SUB))
```

but only receive the error message

> Error in -ivar : invalid argument to unary operator

I've tried altering the class of both variables (i.e.`df$SUB <- as.character(df$SUB)`), as well as ensuring the length of both columns are equal (they are).

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (it's better to post a `dput()` rather than an `str()`). Also explicitly mention any packages you are using, `addLR` is not a base function.

Comment: Is `addLR` from `robCompositions` ?

Comment: This may be what you need for `addLR`: `addLR(df, ivar=ncol(df))`.